# ~ no response on stdout ~ in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    int a,query,in,n,b[n],sum[a];
    sum[1]=0;
    scanf("%d",&query);

    for(a=1;a<=query;a++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&in);
        for(n=1;n<=in;n++)
        {
            b[n]=1+7*(n-1)+6*(n-1)*(n-2)+(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3);
            sum[a]=sum[a]+b[n];
        }
    }

    for(a=1;a<=query;a++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",sum[a]);
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

I have made this code which is running in terminal .

But in hacker rank it is showing

Input (stdin)

```
2

2

5
```

Your Output (stdout)

```
~ no response on stdout ~
```

Expected Output

```
9

225
```

Compiler Message

```
Segmentation Fault
```

Now what should I do to solve the problem .

Comment: `b[n],sum[a]` ? `n` and `a` are uninitialized. Turn your warnings on. And arrays are `0`-based, so your loops are invalid too.

Comment: @EugeneSh. you mean I should define what are n and a .like int a,n;

Comment: No, I mean they are *uninitialized*, i.e. do not have a defined value.

Comment: @EugeneSh. so what should I do to solve the problem

Comment: You need to assign some values to them during the declaration for example: `int a = 10, n = 943;`

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I have assinged the values as : a=query; and n=in; .     But then also it is showing the same error.

Comment: @user123733 You need a good C book and learn the basics of the language. query and in the are uninitialized as well. There is no way to make the table of the size which is given by the scanf except the dynamic allocation.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Can you please help me in this . What should I do to solve this problem

Comment: Was too long for the comment

Comment: "Segmentation fault" is not a compiler message; it occurs at execution time. Also, the usual message is `Segmentation fault`, not `Segmentation Fault`. The difference between `fault` and `Fault` may seem trivial, but it indicates that you didn't copy-and-paste the error message. Re-typing source code, program output, or error messages into your question can cause errors that can seriously interfere with attempts to diagnose the problem. (Not in this case, but in general.)

Comment: Also, while you're at it, don't use `scanf()` to read user input. (It is usually preferrable to `fgets()` a whole line of input, and then make sense of it using the various `str...()` funktions -- much less error-prone, and easier to debug.) And if you *do* use `*scanf()`, at least check the return value of the function to make sure you actually *did* read a valid value (instead of using the value *uninitialized* as Eugene pointed out...

Answer (score 2):

Your variables are uninitialized. As a result your program invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

For example you do not initialize `n`, but you then declare `int b[n]`. What is the size of array `b`? Nobody really knows, since `n` has a garbage value.

Start by figuring out what the values of your variables should be, and then start coding.

---

Array indexing starts from 0, thus your for loops are not looking good.

Change this:

```
for(a=1;a<=query;a++)
```

to this:

```
for (a = 0; a < query; a++)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    int a, query, in, n, *b, *sum;
    scanf("%d",&query);

    sum = malloc(query * sizeof(int));

    /* do some checks if the malloc was successful */ 

    for(a = 0; a < query; a++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&in) ;    /* you should check if scan has returned 1 */
        b = malloc(in * sizeof(int)); /* and again check against any allocation errors */

        for(n = 0; n < in; n++)
        {
           b[n] = 1+7*(n)+6*(n)*(n-1)+(n)*(n-1)*(n-2);
           sum[a] = sum[a] + b[n];
        }
        free(b);
    }

    /* the rest */
```

Comment: This is still bad, but better than OP's code.

Comment: As I commented it is only to show him the idea - not the actual code . I am not going to do his home work

Comment: I see Peter, agreed. I posted an answer on the same logic..What do you think of it? +1 for yours.

Comment: `sizef(int)` ??

Comment: @M.M it should quite obvious typo for someone who is supposed to know the C

Answer (score 0):

In `int a,query,in,n,b[n],sum[a];`, the value of `a` is not initialised and is having garbage value which could be anything. This value is used as the size of the variable length array `sum`. So the size of the array could be anything which is probably not what you want.

`a` could be `0` in which case `sum` is an array of size `0` which will in turn make `sum[1]` incorrect (it would be undefined behavior).

The same applies to `n` and `b[n]`.

In the nested `for` loop, with `sum[a]=sum[a]+b[n];` you are using `sum[a]` which has not been initialised. It has garbage value and the result is indeterminate.

If you wanted all elements of `sum` to be initialised with `0`, you can do

```
int sum[20]={0};
```

at the time of declaring it.

The same goes for `b[n]=1+7*(n-1)+6*(n-1)*(n-2)+(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3);` as well.

And array indexing starts at `0`.
Perhaps you could use the loops like

```
for (a = 0; a < query; a++) {
```

instead of

```
for (a = 1; a <= query; a++)
```

If you choose the starting index as `0`, the inner nested loop should be like

```
for(n=0;n<in;n++)
{
    //b[n]=1+7*(n-1)+6*(n-1)*(n-2)+(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3);
    b[n]=1+7*(n)+6*(n)*(n-1)+(n)*(n-1)*(n-2);
    sum[a]=sum[a]+b[n];
}
```

See [demo](https://ideone.com/lBRoiX).

Comment: It's undefined behaviour as soon as `b[n]` is defined. Your answer incorrectly says that it depends on what `a` "could be".  Garbage value is garbage value (the formal term is "indeterminate"), it's not  like rolling a random number and then proceeding in a well-defined fashion after that

Comment: @M.M Can you explain? Why won't it proceed in a proper fashion with the indeterminate array size?

Comment: Because `b[n]` causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) which means that the program is no longer covered at all by the definition of the C language

Comment: @M.M But wouldn't that be a variable length array? Isn't that legal?

Comment: It's not legal to declare one with indeterminate value as the dimension

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
int a,query,in,n,b[n],sum[a];
```

What is the meaning of `b[n]`? And of `sum[a]`? Assuming that you would like to have a language with *magically* growing arrays, C is a bad choice.

In C language arrays are a structure with size known at compile time. Anyway, let's assume that your compiler supports the horrible hack of variable-length arrays. You can do this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, query, in , n;
    scanf("%d", &query);
    int sum[query+1];

    for (a = 1; a <= query; a++) {
        sum[a] = 0;
        scanf("%d", &in);
        int b[in+1];
        for (n = 1; n <= in ; n++) {
            b[n] = 1 + 7 * (n - 1) + 6 * (n - 1) * (n - 2) + (n - 1) * (n - 2) * (n - 3);
            sum[a] = sum[a] + b[n];
        }
    }

    for (a = 1; a <= query; a++) {
        printf("%d\n", sum[a]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note the changes: first you need to know the size of the array, then you can allocate it. Moreover, I increased the size of the array in order to support your choice of starting from 1. Lastly I also zeroed the initial value for `sum` array.

Comment: It will not work my friend. It does not change anything. potting the scanf between the variable declarations will not help. Space for them is allocated on the function entry. It would work if your compiler supports code blocks local variables, but is hat to be written a different way     scanf("%d", &query); {
    int sum[query+1]; ..... } - you need to wrap it into the separate code block.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: The standard says "6.2.4.6 For such an object that does have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends from the declaration of the object until execution of the program leaves the scope of the declaration." So, the space for them is not allocated on the function entry, but after their declaration.

Comment: @PeterJ_01: Test it here https://ideone.com/aysSNw. Of course it will not work in compilers which do not support variable-length arrays, such as the Microsoft C Compiler.

Comment: Disagree with calling VLAs a "horrible hack" . Just about every other programming language has runtime array sizing,  this improvement to the language just helps to bring it out of the dinosaur era.  Also your statement that array sizes are known at compile-time is false., as demonstrated by your program

Comment: @M.M: "Just about every other programming language has runtime array sizing", unfortunately variable-length arrays sizes cannot change after allocation. So you get a language construct which can solve some of the problems of arrays, but not enough. And is not portable, because now (C11) it is an optional feature.

Comment: True enough about the resizing;  however all compilers support it except MSVC which is a political issue (they refuse to implement it due to being immature about the standardization process)